# How do I properly change the MAC address of my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, command-line, mac-address

I am unable to change my MAC address using `sudo ifconfig en0 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`. I was previously able to do it before I completely erased my Mac and reinstalled macOS Catalina.

Does anyone know how to change it and why its not changing? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is correct, once you've prepared the network to be changed. Temporarily power down the WiFi before changing the address.

Doesn’t work on newer macbooks (2018 and later)

```bsh
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```

Modify the mac address with the desired value:

```bsh
sudo ifconfig en0 ether 88:63:11:11:11:11
```

Finally, turn on the WiFi

```bsh
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

I verified  with Catalina 10.15.4 and 10.15.5

```bsh
uname -a
Darwin iMac.local 19.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.5
BuildVersion:   19F101
```

Comment: What is the difference to the command the OP tried?

Comment: Do you mean ```sudo ifconfig en0 down``` ```sudo ifconfig en0 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx``` ```sudo ifconfig en0 up```?

Comment: To power of WiFi use: 
```bash
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```

Comment: Also notice that my iMac is SIP enabled:


```bash
elulcao@iMac  ~  sudo csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.
```

Comment: In Catalina 10.15.7, this results in `ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Device power is off`

Comment: @gmw That's because your device is powered off. 
Turn WiFi device off, turn the WiFi device on `networksetup -setairportpower en0 on` and then use `ifconfig`.